# Fatal Error Out of memory when trying to access PHP info utility in ee control panel

Tags: ee2

I'm using EE 2.5.5 and noticed recently that the php info tool is showing this error when accessed:

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 10485760) (tried to allocate 131121 bytes) in /home/curvedes/public_html/mercytouch2/system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/tools_utilities.php on line 2096

Any suggestions on how this should be fixed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to increase your [PHP memory limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) in your php.ini file.

Your server administrator can configure this for you if you have no access to your PHP configuration. If you run a local environment using Mamp or Wamp, you can edit the php.ini and find where it says `memory_limit = 32M` (integer may vary so search for memory_limit)

Increase to a higher number like 128M and save the file. Restart the server.

Mamp Pro Example
http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/increase-php-memory-limit-with-mamp-pro.html