# Database error number 5

Tags: ee2, error, database

I had a problem with my Expression Engine. Today login for my system and i have a error off database number 5.

can someone help me?

[image: Error]

Comment: Please let us know what version of ExpressionEngine you are running. Also, have you tried searching for the error message? It might be that you just need to increase the memory on your server, and/or talk to your system administrator about any changes that may have happened on the server side. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10372/fatal-error-out-of-memory-when-trying-to-access-php-info-utility-in-ee-control-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an out of memory error.  This is happening when you just login?

How much memory do you have allocated for this account?

For now, try to repair and optimize your database tables and see if that helps to alleviate this.

Also, it can be more helpful to copy and paste the error as text. For one thing, then it is readable (your screenshot is quite small), and also, it's easier to grab for searching. :)